# WinForms, переменная форма заполнения

Tags: c#, c, winforms

Есть MenuStrip, по нажатию разных вкладок которого в одной и той же форме появляются разные поля для заполнения.  Вопрос как это проще сделать?  Можно, конечно, написать отдельный метод, который будет программно удалять все прошлые контролы от старой вкладки и создавать новые,  задавая положения и все прочие свойства,  но это слишком нерационально, я думаю. Нельзя ли как-то заранее заготовить отдельные компоненты, в которых будут уже содержаться поля для ввода и просто в зависимости от вкладки привязывать этот конкретный компонент к форме?  Заранее спасибо.

Comment: погуглите [UserControls](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=UserControls)

Comment: А почему для вкладок используется MenuStrip? Это Ваш такой дизайнерский (в плане проектирования) подход?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно реализовать во владках. Есть два варианта. Первый упрощенный для среднего количества вкладок, проще в реализации и редактировании. Второй - для любого количества вкладок, можно сказать профессиональный (но его не рекомендую использовать, если вы только начинаете).

1. Создаешь все в TabControl. При выборе меню активируешь нужную вкладку. Вначале перед появлением формы устанавливаешь невидимыми эти вкладки. Только надо учесть, что при сокрытии вкладок размер чуть изменится. Но при правильной компоновке проблема не должна возникнуть, так как есть Anchor.
2. Создаешь для каждого случая UserControl. По выборе меню удаляешь с контейнера (Panel) предыдущий контрол, динамически добавляешь новый.

Все. Элементарно.

Comment: Да,спасибо,делал вторым способом,ибо вкладки уже были изначально.